# Titanium Appcelerator: Creating a TextField in a TableView

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I have tried several different things.  I got the text field to display in the table view (I want a table of text fields) but text is not appearing in the field as I type.  The keyboard is coming up and it is clickable.  The same text field works great when not in a table view.

```
 textFields['user'] = Ti.UI.createTextField({
width:"100%", height:50,
softKeyboardOnFocus : Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS
 });

 ....

 var myRows = [];

 var myRow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:50, touchEnabled:false});
 myRow.add(textFields['user']);

 myRows.push(myRow);

 tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({
data: myRows
 });

 var view = Ti.UI.createView({top:10});
 view.add(tableview);
 serverInfoWinInstance.add(view);
```

I have tried adding the tableview directly to the window like I normally do but the same thing happens.  I am using Android however I would like this to work on iPhone too.

Comment: When you type, the cursor moves but text does not appear?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and found these bugs documented in appcelerator's jira.  Hope the additional info helps, https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-13567 and https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-1715.

Comment: I had the same problem. had to get rid of the tableview, the answers below didn't work... I don't know if this is a bug of android of appcelerator, but it sucks..

Answer (score 0):

You did not construct the textfield **value** property

```
textFields['user'] = Ti.UI.createTextField({
value : "",  // need construct the value 
width:"100%", 
height:50,
softKeyboardOnFocus : Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS
});
```

Or use:

```
textFields['user'] = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    hintText: 'Enter Name '
    width:"100%", 
    height:50,
    softKeyboardOnFocus : Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that your table row has `touchEnabled : false` which is inherited by all child elements of that table.  So when you add your text field to the table row, they have `touchEnabled : false` as well.